# How to animate a buttons image with imageinsets?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uibutton, uiimage

I want my buttons image to animate when i click on it, and animate backwards when i click again.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLH1k.jpg

I want the arrow on the right (which is an image that is set from the inspector) to animate 90 degrees clockwise(I have a set of images for that) when I click on the button once and animate it back when the button is clicked again

The Button however has a custom class with image insets and i don't know how to animate the image properly.

```
class ButtonWithImage: UIButton {

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if imageView != nil {
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: (bounds.width - 35), bottom: 5, right: 5)
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: (imageView?.frame.width)!)
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried this code :

```
var image1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "img1")!
var image2:UIImage = UIImage(named: "img2")!
btn.setImage(image1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.imageView!.animationImages = [image1, image2]
btn.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
btn.imageView!.startAnimating()
```

but it sets the new image without the imageinsets and the animation never stops but loops over again. When i add

```
btn.imageView!.stopAnimating()
```

the animation does not function at all.

Is there a better way to achieve the wanted animation ?

Comment: There is no animation in your screen shot (and no image either), so it is unclear what you are wishing to do. Illustrate or explain fully and clearly what animation you want to perform.

Comment: @matt i want the arrow on the right to animate 90 degrees clockwise(I have a set of images for that) when I click on the button once and animate it back when the button is clicked again, sorry for missing that part

Comment: @matt the arrow image is set from the inspector

Comment: Okay, so here's a suggestion: why not have the arrow be a sublayer of the button that you provide? That way, you can place it and animate it directly (just rotate the layer). In other words, don't try to do this with the button's image view; the button is just going to snatch that out of your hands. Do it with something the button isn't even aware of.

Comment: @matt sounds like a good idea, I’m gonna try this, thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, by sublayer you mean adding an imageview to the hierarchy ?

Comment: Well, no; that would be a subview. You could do that, but I think it would add complications that a simple sublayer would not. All animation is ultimately layer animation anyway, so you don't lose anything.

Comment: @matt I was afraid you would say that. I have looked up how to add a sublayer to a button but I found it very confusing. Can you recommend a good read about sub layers ? I am pretty new to iOS developing.

Comment: Well, if you want something in-depth and free, you could look at the outdated (and Objective-C) online version of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch16.html Sure it's kind of old, but layers have not really changed, and you can probably mentally translate everything from Objective-C to Swift. In any case the concepts are all there. For animation you'd want to read the next chapter. Personally if I wanted to display an arrow rotating I would have a layer that displays an arrow and just rotate the layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a look at that !